# End UITextView editing when tapping on a UIControl

Tags: ios, uitextview, resignfirstresponder

I'm trying to end editing a `UITextView` when I click a `UIControl` on another cell.

If I tap on a cell containing the `UIControl`, the text view ends editing, as expected. However, when I tap on say, a `UIStepper`, the control responds fine but the text view continues in edit mode.

What mechanism would allow me to "catch" the tap anywhere outside the text view and allow me to exit edit mode? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use endEditing: method:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

In Swift:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: Where would you place this statement? I don't seem to be triggering any outgoing event when I tap the control. Thanks.

Comment: @titusmagnus UIStepper is a UIControl. Add a target for the "ValueChanged" event.

Comment: @rmaddy I know. My UITableView has quite a few cells with UIControls. Having to set them up like you suggest seems a bit overkill. Isn't there a more global way to catch this event and call endEditing:?

Comment: @titusmagnus Nope. You need to handle every case the way you want to. There's no "global" way because everyone might want different behavior.

Comment: That's too bad. Oh well, I have update the code with a combination of two things: 1)` [cell.stepper addTarget:cell action:@selector(stepperValueDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; and 2) [self.tableView endEditing:YES]; Thanks for the help!